# Delaying stub answer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, stub, stubbing, testdoublejs

In my production code I have a function which is blocking program for 10 ms (because of use *execSync*). In my test I used testdouble.js library to stub it:

```
td.when(getSignalStrength()).thenReturn.apply(null, array);
```

However stub is responding immediately and in reality function *getCurrentSignalStrength* is responding after 10 ms. I would like to delay the answer of stub so test would be more similar to reality. I read documentation of testdouble.js:
https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/blob/master/docs/5-stubbing-results.md#delay but unfortunately it seems that *delay* option is not available for *thenReturn* method. So how to delay stub answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to cause testdouble.js to block the thread of execution. Like the documentation says, even `defer` and `delay` are frowned upon.

This sounds like an example of an overly defensive specification; the "answer" in this case is to consider whether you *really* need to block and delay for 10ms. What does this indicate in your design?